# Setting up Fastlane + Match for iOS app with iMessage App Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, imessage-extension

I'm having issues getting our CI server to build our apps (we use Jenkins if that's relevant).

We have previously set up our Jenkins builds to work with Fastlane/Sigh/Gym, however since we have recently added iMessage extensions to our apps, the build process is broken.

Everything that I've read points to the fact that I should be using Match to grab the signing certificates, instead of Sigh, so I've switched to using that.

I was also unable to get Sigh to work because the certs that it generated appeared to ignore the fact that both certs required the App Groups capability (both with the appropriate "group.com.mycomp.myapp" App Group)

I have now had limited success building the apps after switching to Match, on my local dev machine. I now use an array of app identifiers in the Match command.

This does successfully download the certs to the local computer.  (I've also finally managed to get this step working on the CI server, after multiple attempts and backwards and forwards with invalid certs etc)

Next, running Gym succeeds on my local computer, but fails on the CI server with the message:

> Code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'

Looking at the very end of the full log file I can see the message

> Check dependencies
>
> No profiles for 'com.mycomp.appname.iMessage'
>   were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching
>   'com.mycomp.appname.iMessage'.
>
> Code signing is required for product
>   type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'

This lane in our Fastfile looks like this:

```
  lane :production_build do

    # grab the appropriate full paths
    project_path = File.expand_path("./", __FILE__)
    xcodeproj_path = File.join(project_path, 'AppName.xcodeproj')
    xcodeworkspace_path = File.join(project_path, 'AppName.xcworkspace')

    # update the correct entitlements file for production
    srcEntitlements = File.join(project_path, 'AppName-Prod.entitlements')
    destEntitlements = File.join(project_path, 'AppName.entitlements')
    print "copying Entitlements file\n from: #{srcEntitlements}\n to  : #{destEntitlements}\n"
    FileUtils.cp(srcEntitlements, destEntitlements)

    # switch the xcproject details to the appropriate team 
    # (we use different teams for Dev and Prod) 
    update_project_team(
      path: xcodeproj_path,
      teamid: "XYZZY"
    )
    # we have a couple of other steps here to ensure the project configuration
    # uses the correct AppIds but I've excluded them for brevity 

    # download the appropriate certs
    match(type: "appstore",
        app_identifier: ["com.mycomp.appname", "com.mycomp.appname.iMessage"],
        team_name: "Team Name",
        team_id: "XYZZY"
        )

    # These old Sigh commands appear to ignore the App Groups requirements 
    #    sigh(force: true, adhoc: true, app_identifier:"com.mycomp.appname")
    #    sigh(force: true, adhoc: true, app_identifier:"com.mycomp.appname.iMessage")
    gym(scheme: "AppName Production", workspace: xcodeworkspace_path) 
  end
```

I am running the same components and latest versions on both machines:

- XCode v8.1
- Fastlane v1.111.0
- Gym v1.12.1
- Match v0.11.0
- Sigh v1.12.0

I am guessing that this is working correctly on my local dev computer because I am always loading up the project in XCode, which I assume fixes up the cert mappings, whereas on the CI server I don't do this.

How can I correctly map the certs so that this works on the CI server?

Alternatively, how do I set this up so that Sigh generates certs with the correct App Group requirements?